# CRM solution configuration steps

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ms-office, sharepoint-2013

I want to configure and install different softwares for a custom CRM solution.
What I need:

·        TFS Server 2012 – Solution -

·        CRM Dynamics 2011 – Integration with TFS and SharePoint.

·        SharePoint 2013 – Integration

·        Office 2010 Standard integration

I want to know the installation hierarchy mean first I should install tfs server then sharepoint and so on or first sharepoint then tfs..
Please let me know order in which I should install all these products. Also let me know if any of these products conflicts each other and I have separate db server, mean sharepoint front server will be separate and db server will be separate. I one Windows server 2008 R2 server and other server with sql server 2008R2

Comment: Uh oh! The SO brigade has decided to flag things instead of help people. Save yourself and read my answer before it is too late!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That all should work just fine, and all products can share a single database server. For installation order, I recommend:

1. CRM 2011 Server.
2. CRM 2011 Email Router.
3. CRM 2011 SSRS Extensions.
4. SharePoint 2013.
5. CRM/SharePoint integration.
6. Office 2010 and CRM Outlook Addin on client machines.

Verify basic functionality after each step, of course.

TFS doesn't directly relate to the functionality of CRM, and there is no direct integration between the CRM server and TFS. Your developers will want to install the CRM Toolkit and then just connect and use TFS as normal.